# Variation of AM-GM Inequality

Tags: number-theory

On one site, I saw: "By the AM-GM inequality,  $xy ≤ (x^2+y^2)/2$."

How can we get from the original form of the AM-GM ( $\sqrt{xy} \le (x + y) / 2$ ) to this form?

Comment: what happens if you plug in $y=x'^2$ and $x=y'^2$ into the first equation?

Comment: Wait... what do you mean by =′2?
Is that just x squared?  @NinadMunshi

Comment: Also, why would we plug in these values?

Comment: I want to use a different variable since $x=x^2$ doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

Apply the "original" AM-GM inequality to $x$ and $y$ where $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$ to get
$$ab = \sqrt{a^2 b^2} \le (a^2 + b^2)/2.$$

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific:  $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{y} \le \dfrac{(\sqrt{x})^2+(\sqrt{y})^2}{2}= \dfrac{x+y}{2}$ .