# $a<x<b \Rightarrow (a-x)(x-b)<\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that,
for $a<b  ; x\in\mathbb{R} $
$$a<x<b \Rightarrow (a-x)(x-b)\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$$
Any idea to help please.
this what I did :
$$(\frac{a+b}{2}-x)^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow (\frac{a+b}{2})^2 -2\frac{a+b}{2}x+x^2\geq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (\frac{a+b}{2})^2 \geq(a+b)x-x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4} \geq ax+bx-x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4}-ab \geq ax+bx-x^2-ab$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{4} \geq(a-x)(x-b)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{(b-a)^2}{4} \geq(a-x)(x-b)$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Btw, it should be $(a-x)(x-b) \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$, there can be equality.

Comment: the usual convex sum idea says take $x = (1-t) a + t b$  for real $t$  between $0$ and $1.$ See if you can finish from that.  The inequalities you edited in  (below "Can I do that?")  cannot both be true.

Comment: @MartinR I edited my question by giving my answer now I need to know if it correct or not, and where did I use the condition ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variation of AM-GM Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417163/variation-of-am-gm-inequality)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The AM-GM inequality states that for any two positive real numbers, $A$ and $B$, we know that:

$$\frac{A+B}{2}\geq\sqrt{AB}$$

so, by squaring both sides, we obtain that:

$$AB\leq\frac{(A+B)^2}{4}$$

Now, notice that if $a<x<b$ then $x-a$ and $b-x$ must both be positive quantities, so let us substitute $A = x-a$ and $B = b - x$, which gives us:

$$(x-a)(b-x)\leq\frac{(x-a+b-x)^2}{4}$$

But we can tidy this up by cancelling out the $x$'s in the numerator of the fraction, and also we can multiply both $x-a$ and $b-x$ by $-1$ without affecting the equation's validity:

$$(a-x)(x-b~)\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$$

as required

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.